# How to remove JDK and keep JRE in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, java, jdk, openjdk, jre

I've installed JDK-8 on my VPS with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

But I just realized I don't really need JDK and JRE is enough for me since I develope my projects on my laptop in intellij and test them and then I just need to run the final jar file on my server.
So what is the best way to keep JRE and remove the rest of JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Comment: this way I will uninstall jre and install it again!

Comment: @aran So? It'll take <5 minutes